# OpenMP call for recursive call with in for loop

Tags: recursion, parallel-processing, openmp

I have asked a similar question before ,but I have not obtained enough attention to my problem due to the complexity of it , so let me rephrase the whole problem .

```
moveT ChooseComputerMove(state)
{
 moveT bestMove;
 maxMove(state,bestMove);

 return bestMove;
}

int maxMove(state, bestMove)
{

  int v = -1000;

  #pragma omp parallel for 
  for(int i = 0; i< nMoves; i++)
  {

   moveT move = validMoves[i];

   makemove(state,move);

   #pragma omp task 

   rating = -maxMove(state, move);

    if(rating < v)
      {v=rating ; bestMove = move;}

    #pragma omp taskwait   

    Retractmove(state,move)
 }

 return v;
}
```

Is my code semantically correct ; I already have tested it in my code , and it gives me segmentation fault;

Update : Sorry for the spelling mistakes and I have edited my code .

Comment: This isn't C, C has no references.

Comment: `b` isn't even declared in the snippet you are showing us. Sure that you'd have at least to declare it locally. And I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. You call it "semantically correct" but you don't give us a hint on the semantics that it should follow.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I am trying to parallelize a simple minmax algorithm . The whole code is given here <http://ideone.com/KZ4LrO> . I want to parallelize the portion where the computer chooses to give the move . Should I use a #pragma omp criticial and enclose the region from move=moveList[i] to RetractMove(state, move ) or use the normal #pragma omp task and #pragma omp taskwait as shown in the code . I am new to omp so , please , bear with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this a comment. Your explicit task region is incorrectly written and besides that it is also redundant. You spawn only one explicit task in each iteration and then wait for it to finish with the `taskwait`. But since task execution may be deferred, the task itself might execute after the line with the comparison operator. E.g.

```c
#pragma omp task
rating = -maxMove(state, move); // <-- This stmt is the body of the task

if(rating < v)
  {v=rating ; bestMove = move;}

#pragma omp taskwait
```

The body of the task is the next block that follows the `task` pragma.

The actual execution flow might be:

- The task is created but queued.
- The `if(rating < v) ....` statement is executed.
- The `taskwait` construct is hit which blocks execution until all tasks are processed. This initiates the execution of the task.
- The new rating is computed but the value of `v` is never updated since the `if` statement was already executed.

You would rather want to put both statements in a `task` construct and also remove the `taskwait` since it is implied at the end of the parallel region. Since `makemove` modifies the `state` vector, you might want to employ the *single task producer* pattern:

```c
#pragma omp parallel
{
   #pragma omp single nowait
   for(int i = 0; i < nMoves; i++)
   {
      moveT move = validMoves[i], opponentsBestMove;

      makemove(state, move);

      #pragma omp task firstprivate(state)
      {
         // Declare rating here
         int rating = -maxMove(state, opponentsBestMove);

         #pragma omp critical
         if (rating > v) { v = rating; bestMove = move; }
      }

      Retractmove(state, move)
   }

   // An implicit taskwait here
}
```

The task producer loop is run in serial in one thread only (because of the `single` directive). Then at the end of the parallel region there is an implicit task scheduling point, hence the other threads start executing the queued tasks. The `state` is shared by default and has to be made `firstprivate` in order for the task to inherit a private version, otherwise all tasks would modify the same global `state` variable at the same time which would lead to problems. The privatisation of `state` would result in much higher memory usage, hence it is not a good idea to allow tasking up to the bottom of the recursion tree. Rather you should stop generating tasks at a certain level and continue with serial execution. This would also reduce the overhead induced by the explicit tasking.

Another thing to notice - unless special measures are taken, only the top-level call would run in parallel. All other recursive calls would result in nested parallel regions and nested parallelism is disabled by default, which means that deeper recursion levels would automatically execute serially. To enable nested parallelism, either set the environment value `OMP_NESTED` to `true` or put the following call somewhere in the beginning of the program:

```c
#include <omp.h>

...
omp_set_nested(1);
...
// Now call the recursive function
...
```

Beware that this might result in a huge number of concurrent threads.

Comment: Hi, I am running Intel Parallel Studio compiler icpc on Ubuntu ,linux and I got this error ;                                           `OMP: Error #178: Function pthread_create failed:
OMP: System error #1: Operation not permitted
Aborted (core dumped)` . If you have can you view my code where I implemented the AI portion ; MinMax(state,bestMove) at : [http://ideone.com/KZ4LrO ]

Comment: @MotiurRahman, sorry, I run Mac OS X and I don't have access to Intel tools. I have access at my workplace though but now I am on vacation. `pthread_create` might fail if the stack size is too high or if you hit the number of processes limit. Check these limits with `ulimit -a` in the shell.

Comment: @HristoIlliev : Yes, it seems that my computer has a problem allocating so many threads . Is there a process ,(now I am a complete novice in OpenMP) , by which I can destroy threads ,after the function  maxMove(state,move) has returned the relevant value .

Comment: @HristoIlliev: Sorry for disturbing you again . What do I think should I do to my minmax algorithm ( I am trying to parallelize minmax algorithm of tictactoe ) , to utilize the multiple core in my computer . My serial minmax is fine .

Comment: Just run without nested parallelism. Thus the first level would run in parallel. Further levels would be serial but will still run in parallel as descendants of the parallel first level.

Comment: @HristoIlliev: I have messed up omp_num_threads and set up its value to 16 ; then I got this error :' *** glibc detected *** ./a.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0xb6dfcd44 ***
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0xb67feb14 ***
Aborted (core dumped)'. What do you think my default value of OMP_NUM_THREADS should be? Any ideas ?

Comment: Set the number of threads equal to the number of physical CPU cores. This should be a good starting point. Do not enable nested parallelism.

Comment: Sorry @Hristo , I get the same stack and heap messed , if I give the command export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 or 4 ; ( I have dual core processor but 4 threads running according to my CPU monitor ; Intel Core i5). The dumped output is here <http://pastebin.com/0Y4fFBLE > and it will be a pleasure if you can look at my parallel tictacote code here <http://pastebin.com/f20br494 > . Just a simple look at my MinMax function will do a lot of help . Thanks .

Comment: @MotiurRahman, see my updated answer. With this modification (single task producer) the code from pastebin works correctly with more than 1 thread and results in the same computer moves as with `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`. I've compiled the code with GCC 4.7.1 under Mac OS X (note that your initial code also runs without errors given that compiler but resulted in more or less random computer moves).

Comment: Unfortunately the updated code didn't work , it still gives me segmentation fault .Here is the updated code <http://pastebin.com/ZKzUAquJ > I suspect that by enabling omp_set_nested(1) , I have disturbed my linux environment beyond repair . I have to reinstall my linux kernel .

Comment: @MotiurRahman, looks like you have some pretty exotic Linux environment. Your code compiles with GCC 4.7.1 and runs just fine with any number of threads from 1 to 4. Compile with `-g` and without optimisation and run it inside a debugger or a thread analyser in order to find out where exactly the error comes from. The odds of an erroneous program breaking your Linux kernel is practically zero.

Comment: Thanks , for the sarcasm , it will definitely cool my fear of submitting code for final project .I used Intel compiler icpc for compiling the code , and its still dumping me .However, using your direction I have recompiled the code with g++ using the flag -openmp , and it plays fine ; expect when I let the machine play against itself I get two different outputs; one for the serial version  http://pastebin.com/mMy8svbd  and one for the parallel version   http://pastebin.com/kkihyytw  . Should I need to be concerned , or its just okay .

Comment: As for the different resulting gameplays, it is because there are many positions that evaluate to the same score. The serial version would always pick the first one while the parallel version would pick the one that the first thread to run evaluates.

Comment: Thanks Mr Hristo for you help ; all through out . Can you recommend any books where I can learn more about openmp . I was thinking about the Art of Concurrency by Clay Breshears ; is there any other suggestions ?

Comment: @MotiurRahman, some books about OpenMP are referred on the [OpenMP web site](http://openmp.org/wp/resources/#Books). You should probably ask on the [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) site for general books on parallel programming.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve here is to make a parallel recursion call. This can cause you lots of problems.

Assume you have 8 physical threads. As `nMoves` in your case does not exceed 8, that would be perfectly fine to run function `MaxMove` with different arguments in 8 parallel threads. However, in each of these calls you are trying to create another `nMoves-1` threads, so complexity of parallel threads you create is exponentional. You won't gain extra performance from running every function call in parallel as the number of physical threads is finite, so eventually all threads will be busy. Also an overhead cost on creating each thread can be too high comparing with amount of calculations you do inside function call.

I'd remove inner `#pragma omp task` and `#pragma omp taskwait` annotations and leave this code serial inside already created threads.

Your code runs for me and I don't get segmentation fault, but I would assume that this is caused by your approach to parallelization.

Comment: My serial code is fine : my question is whether I can parallelize my serial code; and how can I do it ? I ran my code using Intel Parallel Studio and under the current condition is crashes . If I remove #pragma omp task and #pragma omp taskwait ; the code runs ok ; but I do not get the perfect AI that I would get with my serial code . There is an implementation of parallel minmax algorithm here using cilk from MIT ; its done in cilk which is not supported by current Intel Parallel Studio . <http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/cilk/lecture-3.pdf> ; hence I choose to do it using openmp .

Comment: For your code I would suggest something like [this](http://pastebin.com/PjxpGeQe). When you need to make a parallel min-max search you create a separate thread for each search path. Within every path you run strictly serial code. The similar description of parallel algorithm   for tic-tac-toe game can be found [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.84.7898&rep=rep1&type=pdf).